# Loop through column and check if cell contains specific chars

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in need of help trying to figure if Instr function will do this trick.
In a cell i have some text and numbers  (ex: `Overlay 700 MHz - 06_469`)
See the final numbers? 2 numbers followed by **_** (underscore) or any letter and then 3 more numbers.

Is there any way of searching for this in a specific column and if found, copy only these specific combination? NOTE: it can be anywhere in the cell, in beginning, end, middle, etc.....

Comment: There are ways to do it. Show us what have you tried so far and where you stuck.

Comment: This question confused the mass. Are you looking for "any numbers" with that pattern? You should be more specific, and moreover, the only "code" you provided is the keyword `InStr`. That's not enough, neither as code nor as a description of the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regex] to look for a 'two number-underscore-three number' pattern.

```
Option Explicit

Sub pullSerialNumbers()
    Dim n As Long, strs() As Variant, nums() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set cmat = Nothing
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ReDim Preserve nums(0)

    With ws
        strs = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{3}"
        For n = LBound(strs, 1) To UBound(strs, 1)
            If .Test(strs(n, 1)) Then
                Set cmat = .Execute(strs(n, 1))
                'resize the nums array to accept the matches
                ReDim Preserve nums(UBound(nums) + 1)
                'populate the nums array with the match
                nums(UBound(nums) - 1) = cmat.Item(cmat.Count - 1)
            End If
        Next n
        ReDim Preserve nums(UBound(nums) - 1)
    End With

    With ws
        .Cells(2, "C").Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
        .Cells(2, "C").Resize(UBound(nums) + 1, 1) = _
            Application.Transpose(nums)
    End With

End Sub
```

This assumes that only one match could be found in any one cell. If there could be more then loop through the matches and add each one.

[image]

Comment: Thks @Jeeped, managed to get the _(underscore) and letter with the \w sintax ... good way to learn about Regular Expressions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops    BTW, is there any way to say if it doesnt find any value go to next cell? Thks.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean. It loops through the cells already. Each is tested. It only adds to the results if something matching the pattern is found.

Comment: When it doesnt find the value on the left, on the right column it doesnt leaves a blank cell, instead it shifts it up.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - Using Regular expressions for generic match, solution to clarified problem.

Using Regular Expressions (RegExp) to match the pattern "2 digits, 1 non-digit, 3 digits". You will need to add the Regex reference. In the VBA editor, go to `Tools`>`References` and tick

```
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

Then add the following function to your module:

```
Function RegexMatch(Myrange As Range) As String
    RegexMatch = ""

    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z_\-]{1}[0-9]{3}"
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    strInput = Myrange.Value

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        RegexMatch = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)
    End If
End Function
```

And use it like so:

```
Dim myCell As Range
Dim matchString As String
For Each myCell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    matchString = RegexMatch(myCell)
    ' Copy matched value to another column
    myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = matchString
Next myCell
```

Results:

[image: Regexp]

For more on VBA RegExp, see this SO question:

[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

---

**Original** - using `Instr` for search string match.

You're right, the `Instr` function is what you want, it returns `0` if the string isn't in the string and the index greater than `0` otherwise.

```
Dim myString as String
myString = "Overlay 700 MHz - 06_469"
Dim myDigitString as String
' Use RIGHT to get the last 6 characters (your search string)
myDigitString = Right(myString, 6)

Dim myCell as Range
' Cycle through cells in column A, which are also in the sheet's used range
For each myCell in Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    If Instr(myCell.Value, myDigitString) > 0 Then

        ' Copy cell to another sheet
        myCell.copy Desination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PasteToThisSheet").Range("A1")

        ' If you only want to get the first instance then...
        Exit For

    End If

Next myCell
```

To match the pattern "2 digits, another character, 3 digits" you could use:

```
For each myCell in Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    ' Check that first 2 digits and last 3 digits are in cell value
    ' Also check that they are separated by 1 character
    If Instr(myCell.Value, Left(myDigitString,2)) > 0 And _
       Instr(myCell.Value, Right(myDigitString,3)) > 0 And
       Instr(myCell.Value, Right(myDigitString,3)) - Instr(myCell.Value, Left(myDigitString,2)) = 3 Then

        ' Copy cell to another sheet
        myCell.copy Desination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PasteToThisSheet").Range("A1")

        ' If you only want to get the first instance then...
        Exit For

    End If

Next myCell
```

Comment: OP wants to match a pattern, not an exact string.

Comment: @A.S.H The OP says they have "A string in a cell" and they "want to search for this"... I've added an example to my code so that it doesn't have to be an underscore, but it does match their request...

Comment: 1st of all Thks so much for the aswers and sry for my late reply!About the topic, forgot to say that i wanted for to copy the found "Result" to another cell in the same sheet. Wolfie thks so much also for the code, however, the only difference is that I cannot define what I'm searching for, what I mean is, I only know that I need to be looking for 2 numbers followed by  _ (underscore) or any letter and then 3 more numbers. Jeeped, also thks so much. My only questions for the part you provided, is there any way to add the condition 1 letter to the same part of the _(underscore)?

Comment: Hi @EdN, I have made a large edit to use Regular Expressions. I believe this now suits your needs.

Comment: @Wolfie Thks!!! it did the trick, and it ignores the one's that do not correspond and jumps to next row.... will the screenupdate function help improve speed, cause I've been tempering a bit and with a lot of entry's it will be a bit slow.

Comment: @Wolfie, sry to bother but how can i start in row 2 if i have headers? Thks

Comment: At this stage you should be trying to understand the code and looking how you can adapt it. I'm cycling through all cells in the used range of column A: `Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)`. You can change this range to any range! So just use `ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)`

Comment: @EdN If this answers your question and you're still having problems with the accepted answer, then accept this one...

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **D**:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("D:D"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        s = r.Value
        If s <> "" And InStr(s, "_") <> 0 Then
            ary = Split(s, "_")
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Right(ary(0), 2) & "_" & Left(ary(1), 3)
            End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

There are several issues with this approach:

- an underscore at the beginning or end of the text
- more than one underscore in the string
- an underscore surrounded with letters.

Comment: Excellent. At first I thought you assumed the pattern is at the end. :)

Comment: The only remaining issue is if the "_" appears also elsewhere in the text ;)

Comment: @Gary's Student is there a way of searching also instead of the underscore a letter? Any letter from A-Z ?